# Open Source Plug-Play Enterprise Search Engine Options?

Tags: search, solr, amazon-web-services, search-engine, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been researching and testing various Search Engine options but seem to be having the same problem - not finding a good, plug-play Open Source Enterprise Search Engine. By plug-play I mean a search engine I can drop-in, setup my fields, add data and customize the look of the UI (search results, facets, etc). The search would also need to scale easily without an army of techies overseeing it.

I like Solr, but it's not plug-play for the "non-techie" people. I was considering dropping a "configure" Solr into AWS beanstalk but the few posting on that (some were on stackoverflow) were not very informative or clear.

I really would like a Solr in a box that I can drop into AWS beanstalk and focus on adding data to the search engine. Do anyone know of a solution or similar option?

I tested Searchblox in AWS beanstalk. It's the best plug-play option I've seen so far, however, it seems it does not support facets or many features normally found in a Enterprise Search Engine.

I've considered "hosted" solutions like websolr and AWS CloudSearch. Still, these options are not plug-play and need a techie to connect in ... they're also not cheap when you want to have 10 million or more docs.

Do anyone have any suggestions for a Open Source Plug-Play Enterprise Search Engine that could be dropped into a scalable cloud solution like AWS Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

[elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) is a good option. It is open source, distributed and especially built for cloud to scale. It is built on top of Apache Lucene. You'll have to put in some efforts. Connecting CloudSearch seems to be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I just spent a day installing elasticsearch today. The inital install is pretty easy, but what you get is just an engine that you can "program" / "configure" and query using json/rest.  I was hoping for a plug and play search engine, but elasticsearch is far from that.  (I am sure its great when what you need is an engine that you can "dress up" as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Google Search Appliance , Fast Search or other applications for Coveo, Autonomy are few ESearch engines which might satisfy your needs of plug and play .